# C : Input file does not sort in array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, input, is-empty

could I get any hint about my code ? All i get is empty black screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 20
int main()
{
int num,c, i, j, temp, array[20];

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");  //Opening a file
if (fp == NULL)
{
    printf("File empty! \n");
    return 1;
}

while(i < MAX)
{
    fgets(fp, "%d", &array[i]);
    printf("\nARRAY %d",array[i]);
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);
*
*
*more code will be added

return 0;
}
```

Input.txt contains:
0005
0006
FFFF
0007
0003
FFFF
0004
0002
0001
FFFF
0000

Also, when the input.txt is empty, does not give error. I am trying to add these numbers from input into array[i] so how could sort them. 
Any hint/help will help.
Thank you.

Comment: `while(i < MAX)` -- What's the value of `i`?

Comment: Ask yourself what value `i` has when you do: `while(i < MAX)` ? If your answer is "I have no idea", you're in good company, because neither does the program. `i` is *uninitialized*. Even *evaluating* it invokes *undefined behavior*. And the order of your parameters in your `fgets` invoke are wrong: `fp` should be the *last* parameter; not the first. And `fgets` expects a `char` buffer, not an `int` buffer, so I suspect you meant to use `fscanf`. I can't fathom how your compiler didn't at-least warn you about these.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  2) following the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: this statement: `printf("File empty! \n");` has a few problems.  1) route error messages to stderr, not stdout.  2) "file empty" is not the current state, the problem is the call to `fopen()` failed, and the OS knows why.  Use: `perror( "fopen to read input.txt failed" );`

Comment: before trying to 'run' that code you need to get a clean compile. Always enable all the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings. == using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu99 -c myfile.c -o myfile.o` the compiler outputs 10 warnings, several of which are critical,,

Comment: @user3629249 I was compiling inside code::blocks, but surely this method will help in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the things wrong in your code:

- `i` is uninitialized. Evaluating uninitialized data invokes *undefined behavior*, the root of most evil in C programs (and pretty much anywhere else). Severity: **critical**.
- The call to `fgets` is not correct. The parameter list you're providing suggests you should be using `fscanf`. Severity: **Fatal** (will not compile).
- The format flag for reading hexadecimal data is wrong. It should be `%X`. Severity: **Medium-High**, your code will stop reading as soon as the first `FFFF` is encountered, thus giving you inaccurate results.
- The reading operation should be checked for success. Severity: **Medium-High**. You should stop reading once no more values can be scanned in.

There are other things that, though not critical, are advised. Your sizing counter is `int`, but is supposed to represent a magnitude of objects. Thus it should be an unsigned type. The standard library provides a type it uses for such operations, `size_t`, and I advise you use it here.

All of the above rectified in the following, which includes a braindead-simple bubble-sort to perform your actual sorting operation (the algorithm of which is available in roughly a million places on the web).

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 20

void bubblesort(int ar[], size_t count);

int main()
{
    int array[MAX];
    size_t count=0;

    // open input file
    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");  //Opening a file
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File empty! \n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // read all integers from the file
    for (count=0; count<MAX && fscanf(fp, "%X", array+count) == 1; ++count)
        printf("%04X ", array[count]);
    putc('\n', stdout);

    // close file, no longer needed
    fclose(fp);

    // sort the integers
    bubblesort(array, count);

    for (size_t j=0; j<count; ++j)
        printf("%04X ", array[j]);
    putc('\n', stdout);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

// simple bubblesort
void bubblesort(int ar[], size_t count)
{
    int swapped = 1;
    while (count-- && swapped)
    {
        swapped = 0; // reset swap flag
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
        {
            if (ar[i] > ar[i+1])
            {
                int tmp = ar[i];
                ar[i] = ar[i+1];
                ar[i+1] = tmp;
                swapped = 1; // swapped; set flag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Input** (from `input.txt`)

```
0005 0006 FFFF 0007 0003 FFFF 0004 0002 0001 FFFF 0000
```

**Output**

```
0005 0006 FFFF 0007 0003 FFFF 0004 0002 0001 FFFF 0000 
0000 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 FFFF FFFF FFFF
```

Best of luck.

Comment: I should use Insertion Sort instead of bubble sort. Do I need that line "void bubblesort(int ar[], size_t count);" or can i replace "bubblesort with InsertionSort ?

Comment: Use whatever sort you want. That is as simple as they come. If you want a NlogN sorting algorithm the standard library provides one already with [**qsort**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). The only reason I used a bubblesort is because (a) its brain-dead simple to implement (obviously), (b) it is insanely cache friendly for tiny lists like this, and (c) does not use the overhead of the `void*` data abstraction of `qsort`. If this were more than a hundred or so items, I'd probably have insertion-sorted, and for something over a thousand or so, probably merge-sorted or qsorted.